# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type has no compatible call signatures 2349

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Trying to call a getter and a setter in my service and getting the error:
`Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Boolean' has no compatible call signatures 2349`

```
toggleNav(): void {
    this.sidebarService.sidebarStatus.pipe(
        concatMap((bool: boolean) => this.sidebarService.updateStatus(bool))
    );
}
```

After reading several SO pages about this I have yet to read a simple answer. Can someone explain what this error means in plain Engrish?

**Here are the setters and getters:**

```
private _sidebarStatus = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

public get sidebarStatus(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._sidebarStatus.asObservable();
}
public set updateStatus(bool: boolean) {
    this._sidebarStatus.next(bool);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to use properties (as you define with `get`/`set`) then you just need to assign the property when you want to set it, the call to the setter will happen automatically.

```
this.sidebarService.sidebarStatus.pipe(
    concatMap((bool: boolean) => this.sidebarService.updateStatus = bool)
);
```

The error you are getting is because the compiler treats `this.sidebarService.updateStatus` as a boolean field (as it should, the get/set is an implementation detail, properties behave in the same was syntactically as any field would) and thus you can't call a boolean value.

You can also drop the `set` and then you can call `updateStatus` as you try to do as it would just be a regular method not a property setter :

```
public updateStatus(bool: boolean) {
    this._sidebarStatus.next(bool);
}
this.sidebarService.sidebarStatus.pipe(
    concatMap((bool: boolean) => this.sidebarService.updateStatus(bool)) // ok now
);
```

You get read more about property accessors [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) under the heading Accessors

Comment: Thanks Titian, that's informative. But it gives `Argument of type '(bool: boolean) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: boolean, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.ts(2345)`

Comment: @TR3B Maybe `concatMap((bool: boolean) => { this.sidebarService.updateStatus(bool) })` is this the line you are getting the error on ?

Comment: Yes that's the one

Comment: @TR3B did you try with the extra `{}` as in the comment above ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not seeing double `{}` in the comment but yes I've tried code as your answer and a few different variations. There must be something I'm doing to cause this consistent error?

Comment: @TR3B I did not create a full example for this, but I would expect it to work .. I will come back with a contained example

Comment: @TR3B  `concatMap` expects you to return a new observable, if you want to be notified of the value, why not use `subscribe` ?

Comment: Hmm I was trying to avoid subscription management. But you're correct, it does need an Observable!